# Custom Activity transition when up button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

Whenever I press the up button from my current **activity**, parent fragment slides in towards the left from the right edge, which seems to be the default transition behavior.But i want the parent activity to slide in rightwards from the left edge.

I already used `onBackPressed` with `overridePendingTransition` and custom transition xml files but my `onBackPressed` is never called.

Here is my java code.

```
public class TakeOrderItems extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_order_items);

    //Get the actionbar to set the back button
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

/* 
  CODE TO CREATE AND DISPLAY EXPANDABLELISTVIEW
                                               */


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.i("Good","back pressed");
    overridePendingTransition(R.transition.slide_in,R.transition.slide_out);
}
```

XML transition files

slide_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

slide_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

I have checked many answers but they seems to be confusing and contradictory.I think there must be an elegant and efficient way to achieve this since many many apps use this.Please please help me.Thanks.

Comment: you can try this ,
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        
    }

Comment: @Vadivel I can't understand what this code is supposed to do.Can you please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Up* navigation button is handled by `onOptionsItemSelected`. So override it:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Note that this `onOptionsItemSelected` implementation assumes that your parent activity is already started, and is the next one on your backstack. You'll may want to start it in addition to finish the current one.

Override the `finish` method of your `Activity` to set the transition:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
}
```

Also, it looks like you're confused by the `overridePendingTransition` method name. It takes *animations* as parameters, not *transitions*.

This would be your `slide_in` equivalent:

```
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shareInterpolator="false">

  <translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="200"/>

</set>
```

And the `slide_out`:

```
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shareInterpolator="false">

  <translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="200%"
    android:duration="200"/>

</set>
```

Just put those files in `res/anim` instead of `res/transition`.

Comment: Can you please explain, how to create anim.slide_in ?

Comment: Thanks.But the finish is also not called.I have checked it using logs.

Comment: Oh well, sorry, I overlooked your question. Using the *Up* button indeed doesn't call `finish()`. I updated the answer to handle the *Up* case.

Comment: A big thank you.Got it.By the way, i think  you typed the method name as onUpdateItemSelected instead of onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: Good catch! My copy/paste skills abused me ;-) Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on API 21 in the emulator. I'm also using app.Activity not AppCompatActivity. Having this code still doesn't override the transition on 'up' button

Answer (score 1):

Put `overridePendingTransition` above call `super.onBackPressed()` it must work